# Bash Script: Grabbing First Item Per Line, Throwing Into Array

Tags: oracle, bash, shell, awk, grep

I'm fairly new to the world of writing Bash scripts and am needing some guidance. I've begun writing a script for work, and so far so good. However, I'm now at a part that needs to collect database names. The names are actually stored in a file, and I can grep them.

The command I was given is `cat /etc/oratab` which produces something like this:

```
# This file is used by ORACLE utilities.  It is created by root.sh
# and updated by the Database Configuration Assistant when creating
# a database.

# A colon, ':', is used as the field terminator.  A new line terminates
# the entry.  Lines beginning with a pound sign, '#', are comments.
#
# The first and second fields are the system identifier and home
# directory of the database respectively.  The third filed indicates
# to the dbstart utility that the database should , "Y", or should not,
# "N", be brought up at system boot time.
#
OEM:/software/oracle/agent/agent12c/core/12.1.0.3.0:N
*:/software/oracle/agent/agent11g:N
dev068:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y

dev299:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y

xtst036:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y

xtst161:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y
dev360:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
dev361:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
xtst215:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
xtst216:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
dev298:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.03:Y
xtst160:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.03:Y
```

I turn turned around and wrote `grep ":/software/oracle/ora" /etc/oratab` so it can grab everything I need, which is 10 databases. Not the most elegant way, but it gets what I need:

```
dev068:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y
dev299:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y
xtst036:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y
xtst161:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y
dev360:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
dev361:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
xtst215:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
xtst216:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
dev298:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.03:Y
xtst160:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.03:Y
```

So, if I want to grab the name, such as dev068 or xtst161, how do I? I think for what I need to do with this project moving forward, is storing them in an array. As mentioned in the documentation, a colon is the field terminator. How could I whip this together so I have an array, something like:

```
dev068
dev299
xtst036
xtst161
dev360
dev361
xtst215
xtst216
dev298
xtst160
```

I feel like I may be asking for too much assistance here but I'm truly at a loss. I would be happy to clarify if need be.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the results without storing them in an array first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much simpler using awk:

```
awk -F: -v key='/software/oracle/ora' '$2 ~ key{print $1}' /etc/oratab

dev068
dev299
xtst036
xtst161
dev360
dev361
xtst215
xtst216
dev298
xtst160
```

To populate a BASH array with above output use:

```
mapfile -t arr < <(awk -F: -v key='/software/oracle/ora' '$2 ~ key{print $1}' /etc/oratab)
```

To check output:

```
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="dev068" [1]="dev299" [2]="xtst036" [3]="xtst161" [4]="dev360" [5]="dev361" [6]="xtst215" [7]="xtst216" [8]="dev298" [9]="xtst160")'
```

Comment: [Reference: Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Comment: It seems our version of Bash doesn't have the MAPFILE command. Is there an alternative option?

Comment: Yes you can also do: **`arr=$(awk -F: -v key='/software/oracle/ora' '$2 ~ key{print $1}' /etc/oratab)`**

Answer (score 1):

We can pipe the output of `grep` to the [`cut`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)) utility to extract the first field, taking colon as the field separator.

Then, assuming there are no whitespace or glob characters in any of the names (which would be subject to [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion)), we can use a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) to run the pipeline, and capture the output in an [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) by assigning it within the parentheses.

```
names=($(grep ':/software/oracle/ora' /etc/oratab| cut -d: -f1;));
```

---

Note that the above command actually makes use of word splitting on the command substitution output to split the names into separate elements of the resulting array. That is why we must be sure that no whitespace occurs *within* any single database name, otherwise that name would be internally split into separate elements of the array. The only characters within the command substitution output that we want to be taken as word splitting delimiters are the [line feeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) that delimit each line of output coming off the `cut` utility.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `awk` for this:

```
awk -F: '!/^#/ && $2 ~ /^\/software\/oracle\/ora-/ {print $1}' /etc/oratab
```

The first pattern excludes any commented-out lines (starting with a #). The second pattern looks for your expected directory pattern in the second field. If both conditions are met it prints the first field, which the Oracle SID. The `-F:` flag sets the field delimiter to a colon.

With your file that gets:

```
dev068
dev299
xtst036
xtst161
dev360
dev361
xtst215
xtst216
dev298
xtst160
```

Depending on what you're doing you could finesse it further and check the last flag is set to Y; although that is really to indicate automatic start-up, it can sometime be used to indicate that a database isn't active at all.

And you can put the results into an array with:

```
declare -a DBS=(`awk -F: -v key='/software/oracle/ora' '$2 ~ key{print $1}' /etc/oratab`)
```

and then refer to `${DBS[1]}` (which evaluates to `dev299`) etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like them into a Bash array:

```
$ cat > toarr.bash
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
    if [[ $line =~ .*Y$ ]] # they seem to end in a "Y"
    then
        arr[$((i++))]=${line%%:*}
    fi
done < file
echo ${arr[*]} # here we print the array arr
$ bash toarr.bash
dev068 dev299 xtst036 xtst161 dev360 dev361 xtst215 xtst216 dev298 xtst160
```